# is there any way to create new .xml activity file connected to .kot or .jav file

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, build.xml

I have accidentally deleted my ARINA.xml (activity) and I am asking for help on how to create a new ARINA.xml file connected to the ARINA.kt file or recover activity (it's on android studio )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create new layout file and name exactly same as the previous(deleted one) as ARINA.xml. Right click on file name > Local History > Show History. File will open with new and previous one side by side. Incorporate the changes on the new file by selecting the parts which are not in new file but in old one.